# If we draw 7 cards from a standard 52 card deck

Tags: probability

If we draw 7 cards from a standard 52-card deck, what is the probability that all 7 cards are hearts?
Probability =

I already did (13/52), (12/51), (11/50), (10/49),(9/48), and (8/47), and it is (7/46) as the answer once I put in as the answer for the problem. I got it wrong. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Can you solve it for $1$ card? how about $2$?

Comment: Well, I thought so.  sorry I am not smart

Comment: It looks like you gave the (conditional) probability ($\frac{7}{46}$) of getting a heart on the seventh card given that the first six cards all were hearts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for putting in your attempt. You have the right pieces, you just need to put them together:

- The probability of the first card being a heart is indeed $13/52$.
- The probability of the second card being a heart *given that the first card was a heart* is indeed $12/51$.
- The probability of the third card being a heart *given that the first two cards were both hearts* is indeed $11/50$.
- And so on.

In these situations, since you need all seven events to happen to succeed, the probabilities must be multiplied together:

\begin{align}
P(\text{all seven cards are hearts})
    & = \frac{13}{52} \times \frac{12}{51} \times \frac{11}{50} \times
        \frac{10}{49} \times \frac{9}{48} \times \frac{8}{47} \times
        \frac{7}{46} \\
    & = \frac{13 \times 12 \times 11 \times 10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7}
             {52 \times 51 \times 50 \times 49 \times 48 \times 47 \times 46}
        \\
    & = \cdots
\end{align}

You can, I imagine, do the cancellation yourself. Note that the fraction in the second line can be written more succinctly, as in Vadim Chernetsov's answer, as

$$
P(\text{all seven cards are hearts}) = \frac{\binom{13}{7}}{\binom{52}{7}}
$$

where

$$
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
$$

is the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). The reasoning, which is more concise, but requires you familiarize yourself with the binomial coefficient's interpretation, is that there are $\binom{52}{7}$ ways to select $7$ cards out of $52$ (all equally likely), of which $\binom{13}{7}$ consist of all hearts.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{\binom{13}{7}}{\binom{52}{7}}.
$$